# Lua: string of specific length

Tags: string, lua, string-length

```
local data = "here is a string"
local no = 12
foo = string.format("%50s %05d",data,no)
print(foo:len(),string.format("%q",foo))
```

defines `foo` as a string of specific length

```
"                                  here is a string 00012"
```

However, is there an *easy* way to get

```
"here is a string                                   00012"
```

I know, that I can fill up the string `data` with spaces

```
while data:len() < 50 do data = data.." " end
```

Comment: Add a minus to format: `%-50s`

Comment: uh, that's simple ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a minus to format string `%-50s` to align text to the left:

```
foo = string.format("%-50s %05d","here is a string", 12)
print(foo:len(), foo)
```

Output:

```
56  here is a string                                   00012
```

Allowed flags:

```
- : left align result inside field
+ : always prefix with a sign, using + if field positive
0 : left-fill with zeroes rather than spaces
(space) : If positive, put a space where the + would have been
# : Changes the behaviour of various formats, as follows:
  For octal conversion (o), prefixes the number with 0 - if necessary.
  For hex conversion (x), prefixes the number with 0x
  For hex conversion (X), prefixes the number with 0X
  For e, E and f formats, always show the decimal point.
  For g and G format, always show the decimal point, and do not truncate trailing zeroes.
  The option to 'always show the decimal point' would only apply if you had the precision set to 0.
```

Comment: how to replace space with '-'?

Comment: @wsha there is another way: `foo = data .. string.rep("-", 50 - data:len()) .. string.format("%05d", no)`